# Write numpy unicode array to a text file

Tags: python, numpy, unicode

I'm trying to export a numpy array that contains unicode elements to a text file.

So far I got the following to work, but doesn't have any unicode character:

```
import numpy as np

array_unicode=np.array([u'maca' u'banana',u'morango'])

with open('array_unicode.txt','wb') as f:
    np.savetxt(f,array_unicode,fmt='%s')
```

If I change 'c' from 'maca' to 'ç' I get an error:

```
import numpy as np

array_unicode=np.array([u'maça' u'banana',u'morango'])

with open('array_unicode.txt','wb') as f:
    np.savetxt(f,array_unicode,fmt='%s')
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-48-24ff7992bd4c>", line 8, in <module>
    np.savetxt(f,array_unicode,fmt='%s')
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1158, in savetxt
    fh.write(asbytes(format % tuple(row) + newline))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe7' in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How can I set `savetxt` from numpy to write unicode characters?

Comment: How would you write these strings if they were a list or longer text?  Would you still open the file in `wb` mode?

Comment: The 'wd' mode is just because only 'w' throws me an error.

Answer (score 4):

In Python3 (`ipthon-qt` terminal) I can do:

```
In [12]: b=[u'maça', u'banana',u'morango']

In [13]: np.savetxt('test.txt',b,fmt='%s')

In [14]: cat test.txt
ma�a
banana
morango

In [15]: with open('test1.txt','w') as f:
    ...:     for l in b:
    ...:         f.write('%s\n'%l)
    ...:         

In [16]: cat test1.txt
maça
banana
morango
```

`savetxt` in both Py2 and 3 insists on saving in 'wb', byte mode.  Your error line has that `asbytes` function.

In my example `b` is a list, but that doesn't matter.

```
In [17]: c=np.array(['maça', 'banana','morango'])

In [18]: c
Out[18]: 
array(['maça', 'banana', 'morango'], 
      dtype='<U7')
```

writes the same.  In py3 the default string type is unicode, so the `u` tag isn't needed - but is ok.

In Python2 I get your error with a plain write

```
>>> b=[u'maça' u'banana',u'morango']
>>> with open('test.txt','w') as f:
...    for l in b:
...        f.write('%s\n'%l)
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe7' in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

adding the `encode` gives a nice output:

```
>>> b=[u'maça', u'banana',u'morango']
>>> with open('test.txt','w') as f:
...    for l in b:
...        f.write('%s\n'%l.encode('utf-8'))
0729:~/mypy$ cat test.txt
maça
banana
morango
```

`encode` is a string method, so has to be applied to the individual elements of an array (or list).

Back on the py3 side, if I use the `encode` I get:

```
In [26]: c1=np.array([l.encode('utf-8') for l in b])

In [27]: c1
Out[27]: 
array([b'ma\xc3\xa7a', b'banana', b'morango'], 
      dtype='|S7')

In [28]: np.savetxt('test.txt',c1,fmt='%s')

In [29]: cat test.txt
b'ma\xc3\xa7a'
b'banana'
b'morango'
```

but with the correct format, the plain write works:

```
In [33]: with open('test1.txt','wb') as f:
    ...:     for l in c1:
    ...:         f.write(b'%s\n'%l)
    ...:         

In [34]: cat test1.txt
maça
banana
morango
```

Such are the joys of mixing unicode and the 2 Python generations.

In case it helps, here's the code for the `np.lib.npyio.asbytes` function that `np.savetxt` uses (along with the `wb` file mode):

```
def asbytes(s):    # py3?
    if isinstance(s, bytes):
        return s
    return str(s).encode('latin1')
```

(note the encoding is fixed as 'latin1').

The `np.char` library applies a variety of string methods to the elements of a numpy array, so the `np.array([x.encode...])` can be expressed as:

```
In [50]: np.char.encode(b,'utf-8')
Out[50]: 
array([b'ma\xc3\xa7a', b'banana', b'morango'], 
      dtype='|S7')
```

This can be convenient, though past testing indicates that it is not a time saver.  It still has to apply the Python method to each element.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways you can accomplish this, however, numpy arrays need to be setup in very specific ways (usually using a `dtype`) to allow unicode characters in these circumstances.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np

dt = np.dtype(str, 10)
array_unicode=np.array(['maça','banana','morangou'], dtype=dt)

with open('array_unicode.txt','wb') as f:
    np.savetxt(f, array_unicode, fmt='%s')
```

You'll need to be aware of the string length in your array as well as the length you decide to setup within the dtype. If it's too short you'll truncate your data, if it's too long it's wasteful. I suggest you read the **[Numpy data type objects (dtype) documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.9.3/reference/arrays.dtypes.html)**, as there are many other ways you might consider setting up the array depending on the data format.

↳ http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.9.3/reference/arrays.dtypes.html

Here's an alternative function that could do the conversion to unicode before saving:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np

array_unicode=np.array([u'maça',u'banana',u'morangou'])

def uniArray(array_unicode):
    items = [x.encode('utf-8') for x in array_unicode]
    array_unicode = np.array([items]) # remove the brackets for line breaks
    return array_unicode

with open('array_unicode.txt','wb') as f:
    np.savetxt(f, uniArray(array_unicode), fmt='%s')
```

Basically your `np.savetxt` will call `uniArray` for a quick conversion, then back. There might be better ways to than this, although it's been a while since I've used numpy; it's always seemed to be somewhat touchy with encodings.

Comment: One of the main reasons to use numpy is to avoid loops. Isn't there a solution using a numpy method or function?

Comment: I'm not clear on why you're even using the `u` in front of your strings.... Is there some compelling reason for that? If you declare an encoding you wouldn't need that. Also there are other ways to do this, and you should read the documentation about `dtypes` and how to use them.

Comment: `savetxt` uses a loop, doing a `file.write(fmt%tuple(row))` for each row of your array.  And any encoding/decodings will be done iteratively with string methods.  Using arrays here won't save you time.

Comment: I'm using 'u' in front of my strings to illustrate my problem, since I want words like 'maça' in my final array. Nice to know that 'savetxt' uses a loop, but I believe that is an optimized one for arrays right?

Comment: I believe my question is about unicode and numpy. Thank you for your answer, but I was looking for an integrated way to work with numpy and 'savetxt', if possible.

Comment: Sorry @l'L'l now I saw that you edited the answer. That was what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @umLu: If it was what you were looking for then why'd you unaccept the answer? o_O

Comment: Sorry @l'L'l, I'm still learning how to use this site (since I don't use it very often). People are coming up with other answers, maybe it's fair just to wait a little more.