# numpy: savetxt Mismatch between array dtype ('int32') and format specifier ('%d')

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to save array using `savetxt`. Here is what I do:

```
import numpy
import sys
a = numpy.asarray(((1,2,3),(4,5,6)))
numpy.savetxt(sys.stdout, a, fmt='%d')
```

What I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\George\Documents\My\contests-penza-su-2016\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1158, in savetxt
    fh.write(asbytes(format % tuple(row) + newline))
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\George\Documents\My\contests-penza-su-2016\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1162, in savetxt
    % (str(X.dtype), format))
TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('int32') and format specifier ('%d %d %d')
```

Similar errors emerge when I try to output flattened array and when I try to output it to file.

Comment: See the `asbytes` function in the 1st error message?  The file must be opened in `wb` mode.  In Python3 default string type is unicode.  `stdout` might work in `py2`.  Check your `savetxt` with a normal file name.

Comment: Could you make answer from your comment? Indeed, I use Python 3.4 and `sys.stdout` has unicode encoding. As I understand (just curious), if format has some multibyte UTF-8 codepoints, output will be done as bytes that are valid UTF-8 sequence?

Comment: I just explored writing UTF-8 characters the other day in http://stackoverflow.com/a/36721261/901925

Comment: That answers all my questions. Thank you!