# Specifying encoding using NumPy loadtxt/savetxt

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, encoding, utf-8

Using the NumPy `loadtxt` and `savetxt` functions fails whenever non-ASCII characters are involved. These function are primarily ment for numeric data, but alphanumeric headers/footers are also supported.

Both `loadtxt` and `savetxt` seem to be applying the latin-1 encoding, which I find very orthogonal to the rest of Python 3, which is thoroughly unicode-aware and always seem to be using utf-8 as the default encoding.

Given that NumPy hasn't moved to utf-8 as the default encoding, can I at least change the encoding away from latin-1, either via some implemented function/attribute or a known hack, either just for `loadtxt`/`savetxt` or for NumPy in its entirety?

That this is not possible with Python 2 is forgivable, but it really should not be a problem when using Python 3. I've found the problem using any combination of Python 3.x and the last many versions of NumPy.

#### Example code

Consider the file `data.txt` with the content

```
# This is π
3.14159265359
```

Trying to load this with

```
import numpy as np
pi = np.loadtxt('data.txt')
print(pi)
```

fails with a `UnicodeEncodeError` exception, stating that the latin-1 codec can't encode the character '`\u03c0`' (the `π` character).

This is frustrating because `π` is only present in a comment/header line, so there is no reason for `loadtxt` to even attempt to encode this character.

I can successfully read in the file by explicitly skipping the first row, using `pi = np.loadtxt('data.txt', skiprows=1)`, but it is inconvenient to have to know the exact number of header lines.

The same exception is thrown if I try to *write* a unicode character using `savetxt`:

```
np.savetxt('data.txt', [3.14159265359], header='# This is π')
```

To accomplish this task successfully, I first have to write the header by some other means, and then save the data to a file object opened with the `'a+b'` mode, e.g.

```
with open('data.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('# This is π\n')
with open('data.txt', 'a+b') as f:
    np.savetxt(f, [3.14159265359])
```

which needless to say is both ugly and inconvenient.

#### Solution

I settled on the solution by hpaulj, which I thought would be nice to spell out fully. Near the top of my program I now do

```
import numpy as np

asbytes = lambda s: s if isinstance(s, bytes) else str(s).encode('utf-8')
asstr = lambda s: s.decode('utf-8') if isinstance(s, bytes) else str(s)
np.compat.py3k.asbytes = asbytes
np.compat.py3k.asstr = asstr
np.compat.py3k.asunicode = asstr
np.lib.npyio.asbytes = asbytes
np.lib.npyio.asstr = asstr
np.lib.npyio.asunicode = asstr
```

after which `np.loadtxt` and `np.savetxt` handles Unicode correctly.

Note that for newer versions of NumPy (I can confirm 1.14.3, but properly somewhat older versions as well) this trick is not needed, as it seems that Unicode is now handled properly by default.

Comment: I've banged my head against this before, but don't recall the details.  `savetxt` insists on writing bytestrings, i.e. the file is opened in 'wb'.  But it should be easy to replicate its action with your own file write.  It just iterates on rows of your array, and writes a formatted line to the file.  If you can format a row of your array satisfactorily, you can write your own csv.

Comment: Similar issues were previously discussed here: [write-numpy-unicode-array-to-a-text-file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36705724/write-numpy-unicode-array-to-a-text-file), [reading-unicode-elements-into-numpy-array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375343/reading-unicode-elements-into-numpy-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least for `savetxt` the encodings are handled in

```
Signature: np.lib.npyio.asbytes(s)
Source:   
    def asbytes(s):
        if isinstance(s, bytes):
            return s
        return str(s).encode('latin1')
File:      /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/compat/py3k.py
Type:      function

Signature: np.lib.npyio.asstr(s)
Source:   
    def asstr(s):
        if isinstance(s, bytes):
            return s.decode('latin1')
        return str(s)
File:      /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/compat/py3k.py
Type:      function
```

The header is written to the `wb` file with

```
        header = header.replace('\n', '\n' + comments)
        fh.write(asbytes(comments + header + newline))
```

[Write numpy unicode array to a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36705724/write-numpy-unicode-array-to-a-text-file) has some of my previous explorations.  There I was focusing on characters in the data, not the header.

Comment: When is one function used over the other? I find that both `loadtxt` and `savetxt` works for my examples just by overwriting `np.lib.npyio.asbytes` (which is really nice!).

Answer (score 2):

A couple hacks:

- Open the file in binary mode, and pass the open file object to `loadtxt`:

  ```
  In [12]: cat data.txt
  # This is π
  3.14159265359

  In [13]: with open('data.txt', 'rb') as f:
      ...:     result = np.loadtxt(f)
      ...:     

  In [14]: result
  Out[14]: array(3.14159265359)
  ```
- Open the file using `latin1` encoding, and pass the open file object to `loadtxt`:

  ```
  In [15]: with open('data.txt', encoding='latin1') as f:
      ...:     result = np.loadtxt(f)
      ...:     

  In [16]: result
  Out[16]: array(3.14159265359)
  ```

Comment: Both works! Can you explain why the last hack works? Does core Python take care of the encoding of the file content before it reaches NumPy? Even so, why doesn't it crash when it encounters the `π`, which is outside of latin-1?

Comment: It doesn't encounter π; it sees the two bytes that in hex are `0xCF` and `0x80` (the UTF-8 encoding of π), and interprets them as two distinct Latin-1 characters.  That's not a problem, though, because they are in a comment so ultimately they are ignored.

Comment: Can any utf-8 character be interpreted as several latin-1 characters, or will the above method break on some characters which doesn't behave so nicely? My choice of π was arbitrary.

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1, there are undefined characters in the "Latin 1" encoding.  But I just created a test file with 256 commented lines of the form `# *\n`, where `*` ranges from 0 to 255, and I was able to read it using the above code.  So as long as all the UTF-8 characters are in comments, it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I don't get why that test is sufficient.