# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128) python 3

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, file, numpy

I need extract specific columns values from TXT file using Python 3.
this is my program

```
import numpy as np
filename = 'tender.txt'
data = np.loadtxt(filename, skiprows=4, usecols=[1])
print(data)
```

here TXT file:

> Департамент агропромислового розвитку  Івано-Франківської обласної
>   державної адміністрації   33645091        відсутній план закупівель і жодних
>   звітів Департамент будівництва, житлово-комунального господарства,
>   містобудування та архітектури Івано-Франківської обласної державної
>   адміністрації 38163425         Департамент охорони здоров'я 
>   Івано-Франківської обласної державної адміністрації   2012875
>   Департамент соціальної політики  Івано-Франківської обласної державної
>   адміністрації 25925236         Департамент фінансів  Івано-Франківської
>   обласної державної адміністрації  2313921      Управління інформаційної
>   діяльності та комунікацій з громадськістю Івано-Франківської обласної
>   державної адміністрації   40452051         "Управління з питань цивільного
>   захисту Івано-Франківської обласної державної адміністрації
>   " 14373087         Управління культури, національностей та релігій 
>   Івано-Франківської обласної державної адміністрації   33645264

when I run my pogram I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tinasosiak/Documents/tender.py", line 3, in <module>
    data = np.loadtxt(filename, skiprows=4, usecols=[1])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 974, in loadtxt
    next(fh)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Have you tried the answers from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41528192/specifying-encoding-using-numpy-loadtxt-savetxt ?

Comment: `numpy.loadtxt` is not meant for this use. It's for reading files containing numerical data. And it expects the file to be ascii encoded. Python has bultin tools for reading text files. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files