# NumPy savetxt/loadtxt encoding unnecessary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, encoding, utf-8

I use NumPy's [`savetxt()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) and [`loadtxt()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) to write and read data to and from disk. I sometimes use non-ASCII characters (e.g. Greek) in the optional heading, as in

```py
import numpy as np
np.savetxt('test.txt', [0], header='σ')
np.loadtxt('test.txt')
```

This works fine. The produced file `test.txt` looks like

```
# σ
0.000000000000000000e+00
```

Both [`savetxt()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) and [`loadtxt()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) have an optional `encoding` argument, which for `savetxt()` defaults to `'latin1'`, which as far as I know cannot represent Greek characters.

**Question**: How come that this works despite the supposed use of `'latin1'`? Should I start specifying `encoding='utf-8'` with `savetxt()` and `loadtxt()`, just to be sure?

**Note**: The usage of non-ASCII characters with `savetxt()` and `loadtxt()` is not possible with older version of NumPy. While writing this, I discovered an [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41528192) of mine about dealing with this limitation.

Comment: I got an error on savetxt (character not encodable). But looking at the code, it is possible that in older version there were some magic (because change of string semantic between python 2 and 3)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Are you using Python 3 and a recent version of NumPy?

Comment: `np.savetxt` uses `utf-8` encoding in my `np.__version__` -> `'1.24.2'` (tested using `hexdump` utility). Python 3.11.2 on Windows 10 with `locale.getencoding()` -> `'cp65001'`.

Comment: @JosefZ Seems reasonable, right? Except the doc says otherwise ...

Comment: Numpy '1.24.2', python 3.11., but my savetxt do not used utf-8 as default (unlike @JosefZ) -- If you use a filename, the default encoding is the system default (so latin1/cp1252 on Windows), if you use an handler, the default will be latin1 (as fallback, e.g. bytestream) or the encoding of the handler)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi So the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) are wrong? They claim that latin1 is the default, with no mention of the system default encoding.

Comment: Yes. I think the documentation is not accurate (the more frequent case, so using `io.open` is not described correctly, but so: better to be explicit on encoding, always.